# Python 3.4, I can't get this password verification program to work

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get this password verification program to work but I keep on getting the message that my password doesn't match or doesn't meet the requirements. The password I'm using to test it does meet and match.

```
enter code here
UPPER = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZ"
LOWER = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
NUMBER = "1234567890"

def main() :
    password1 = input("Enter your password: ")
    password2 = input("Re-enter your password: ")
    validPword = False

while validPword == False :
    validPword = isValidPassword(password1,password2)
    if validPword == True :
        print("That pair of passwords will work.")
    else :
        print("Passwords didn't match or didn't have the required   properties.")
        password1 = input("Enter your password: ")
        password2 = input("Re-enter your password: ")

def isValidPassword(password1,password2) :
    equal = pEqual(password1,password2)
    length = pLength(password1)
    upper = pUpper(password1)
    lower = pLower(password1)
    number = pNum(password1)
    if equal and length and upper and lower and lower == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def pEqual(password1, password2) :
    if password1 == password2 : return True
    else:
        return False

def pLength(password1) :
    if len(password1) >= 8 : return True
    else:
        return False

def pUpper(password1):
    for i in range(len(password1)) :
        if password1[i] in UPPER : return True
        else :
            return False

def pLower(password1):
    for i in range(len(password1)) :
        if password1[i] in LOWER : return True
        else :
            return False

def pNum(password1):
    for i in range(len(password1)) :
        if password1[i] in NUMBER : return True
        else :
            return False

main()
```

Any suggestions what is wrong?

Comment: Updated answer for all cases.

Comment: Note that you should really use [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html) to allow the user to enter a password, as this will (when possible) prevent the user's input from appearing on-screen.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code isn't working because you are trying to check that every character in your password is both upper and lower case. That is obviously impossible.

To greatly simplify your code you can `import re` add something like this to ensure that your password is only letters and numbers and of length 8 or greater.

```
if re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}$", password1)
```

And then simply do a string comparison to check for equality. Making a few modifications, you can try something like the following. The code could be made shorter but I avoided changes that would most likely compromise your understanding. Let me know if there's anything you don't understand.

```
import re

def main() :
    validPword = False
    equalityPword = False

    while (validPword and equalityPword) != True :
        password1 = input("Enter your password: ")
        password2 = input("Re-enter your password: ")        
        validPword = isValidPassword(password1,password2)
        equalityPword = pEqual(password1,password2)
        if validPword == True and equalityPword == True :
            print("That pair of passwords will work.")
            return
        elif validPword == False :
            print("Please only use valid characters and numbers, and ensure your password is long enough.")
        else :
            print("Passwords didn't match.")

def isValidPassword(password1,password2) :
    if re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}$", password1) :
        return True
    else:
        return False


def pEqual(password1, password2) :
    if password1 == password2 : return True
    else:
        return False
main()
```

Comment: I'm only on chapter 5 in the book so we haven't reached stuff like "if re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]*$", password1) :" yet. I did get it to work though. I'll post the working code.

Comment: Okay. For future reference, it is useful to outline which tools you really are allowed to use so that it is possible to make an answer most suitable for your question!